# ExpectedResponseUrl error is Visual Studio 2010 web performance test

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webtest

I have recorded a Web Performance Test in Visual Studio 2010 for a web application that uses Windows Live ID with Secure Token Service for the authentication of the user.

There are two requests in my recording that go to https://login.live.com/ and they work fine on the Visual Studio Test Runner after I recorded the test, but then after about a day later I start to get an error message that states "The value of the ExpectedResponseUrl property does not equal the actual response URL" on the requests mentioned. I understand that I can turn off the Response URL validation rules, but that doesn't fix the root cause of the problem and only masks the symptoms.

I was wondering if anyone knows what is going on here? My guess is that there is cached data at the browser level, but I haven't been able to prove that one way or another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are you recorded a value in one of the post back fields that "expires" after a period of time. I am willing to be the url you are getting back from the request is now an error page.

If you are familiar with C#, I find it is easier to change the test to a coded test and have a really close look at all the fields that are being sent to login.live.com.

You would probably need a fair bit of information on how login.live.com works to really get to the bottom of it.